Displaying Iframes in Moodle Mobile App: Troubleshooting Steps
I am using Moodle LMS
moodle app based on ionic angular
I tried may time to add Ifram inside content of my page or add ifram url in link 
its working in web protal but in mobile its not working showing me that site refuse connection and when edit angular.json file and remove 
"Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy": "require-corp"
the app still reloading
how to allow using my ifram inside the app
can you help me please
i am trying to show ifram of video in moodle page content its work in web portal but not working in mobile app
note that i build app by my self
